# What's the bottleneck for openethereum slow sync speed?

Tags: openethereum

I'm trying to sync a full node with --trace on, on some fast hardware, and I still get slow sync speeds (`Syncing #5409141 0x5994…6a98 16.60 blk/s 1527.2 tx/s 91.8 Mgas/s`). It's hovering between **10-15 blk/s** for a while now.

I'm running the following flags `**--tracing=on --cache-size=64000 --num-verifiers=16**" (note I tried both with and without --num-verifiers, same thing)`

This is running on a **ryzen7 3700** with **128gb of RAM** and **1TB pcie4 NVME SSD**, on a fresh **Linux** install (debian). The most annoying thing is that I can't seem to figure out where the bottleneck is. It's only using 1-2 cores fully, and spawns a couple more processes from time to time. Most of the time, though, the cpu sits idle. Iotop doesn't show anything spectacular in terms of iops, and in any case the nvme should breeze through a ton of reads/writes. I'm kinda stuck.

Am I doing something wrong? Could I speed-up the process?

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck here is **hdd**. Use the **ssd** instead. Also you can try other clients such as erigon for example.

Comment: The question mentionned "NVME HDD". I'm pretty sure there are no hard disk (with platters) using NVMe, so that's just a typo.

Comment: I don't know but googled and it seems like there are. anyway the key things are memory and bandwidth. also it may be useful to turn off the tracing flag